# Limit the TouchDrag Object to X axis only

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I currently have this code, from Flash CS6 code Snippets:

```
function fl_TouchBeginHandler(e:TouchEvent):void
{
    e.target.startTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);
}
function fl_TouchEndHandler(e:TouchEvent):void
{
    e.target.stopTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);
}
```

What I want to do is = limit the draggable OBJECT to be dragged horizontally only.  So that it couldn't be dragged UP nor DOWN.

I have searched here in Stack overflow and haven't found any relevant question/answer to this problem.  thanks.

Comment: You can use the bounds:Rectangle parameter in startTouchDrag() and have it 1px high... Cherniv answer is also valid.

Comment: @Chadyk could you tell me how to use the bounds:Rectangle parameter?  I've searched for it and all i'm still confused about the parameters.  Some said its (x,y,width,height) and some other said its (left,top,right,bottom).  Still couldn't get the hang of it. :/

Comment: It's a Rectangle(x, y, width, height) for the middle horizontal line of a 800x400 document it would be: Rectangle(0, 200, 800, 1). I think (left,top,right,bottom) used to be for AS2. Also I would recommend (from own experience), that unless you need multi-touch support, to go for MouseEvent instead of TouchEvent - performance wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Adobe's official](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS1ca064e08d7aa93023c59dfc1257b16a3d6-7ffe.html) , `Touch Point ID` part , 
 function `onTouchMove` :

```
function onTouchMove(event:TouchEvent) { 
  // ...
    mySprite.x = event.stageX; 
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not home right now, but I'll tryit later tonight.  Seems like it'll work :-).

Comment: yes, you made me realize that there is a "TOUCH_MOVE" function.  Usually I just use the "TOUCH_BEGIN/END" function hahah.  Thanks again!